# $(\infty,n)$ categories whose objects do not form a set

Tags: ct.category-theory

I've got a little confused by some set theory underlying Hopkins-Lurie's survey on classification of topological field theories.

The objects of $(\infty,n)$-categories need to form a set, at least if the definition we take is as some kind of weakened Kan complex. Yet in some examples they give objects clearly do not form sets, for example the $ (\infty,1)$-category of chain complexes $chain_t (k)$.

Is there something I am missing?

Edit: About comment below. I am not sure I understand what Lurie's 1.2.15 says concretely, about the example above. If someone could comment it would be great.

Comment: Isn't this addressed in Section 1.2.15 of HTT? Lurie is using universes. 

Comment: If you believe in categories with a proper class of objects, you also believe in simplicial sets with a proper class of vertices. I don't think any model for higher categories introduces any set-theoretic problems that aren't already there for 1-categories.

Comment: I don't see how it is such a straight forward step, a simplicial set is functor $\Delta ^{op}} \to Set$ what do you replace this by? Granted it's probably my ignorance of set theory. But do proper classes form a category, with Set a subcategory? 

Comment: I should have asked: do classes form a category? And if not, how do you define "simplicial classes". 

Comment: In a large category you have a proper class of objects, a proper class of morphisms, and some operations between them. In a large simplicial set you have a proper class of vertices, a proper class of 1-simplices, a proper class of 2-simplices, etc, with operations between them. It's no more difficult to describe than a large category.
The small/large distinction is enough for many purposes, but sometimes  (e.g. to consider the category of proper classes) you need further sizes (superlarge, ultralarge, ...). That's exactly what universes formalize, within the friendly environment that is ZFC.

Comment: Reference? I don't have a problem with large categories. But what you are describing seems to state exactly: we have a category of classes. Maybe we do I've just never heard of such a thing.

Otherwise, how do you define these operations you alluded to. The restriction map from the proper class of 1-simplices to the proper class of 0-simplices is a morphism of classes, this needs to be functorial, etc. 



Comment: You define these operations in the same way as for large categories, so perhaps you do have a problem with large categories after all. They certainly cannot be discussed using ZFC.

Universes are defined in SGA 4, Expose I. When you use universes all things you consider are sets, so there's not even a category of all sets. You only consider the category of all sets contained in a fixed universe (which is itself a set). 

Comment: Another reference is http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe

Comment: You are right if morphisms form a class I seem to have a problem with that as well, since it is not a Set enriched category. But let's leave this for now. Actually after googling I found some references to categories of classes, having Set as a subcategory although I don't know how standard these are. Can you say precisely what is a "simplicial class", in the most abstract way, I can then study terms of this which I don't understand. Or a reference would be ok. The main point I am struggling is that no matter what we seem to want a functor $\Delta ^{op} \to ...$. 


Comment: A (possibly large) category $X$ consists of two classes $X_0$ and $X_1$ and maps $s,t: X_1\to X_0$, $id: X_0\to X_1$, $m: X_1\times_{X_0}X_1\to X_1$ satisfying the usual relations. A (possibly large) simplicial class consists of classes $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_2$, ... with degeneracy maps $X_i\to X_{i+1}$ and face maps $X_{i+1}\to X_i$ satisfying the simplicial relations. If you're OK with large categories that means you're OK with classes and maps between them, so you should be OK with this definition.

Comment: I think you missed my concern. What are maps of classes? Where is this defined? This is the same question I kept asking above. If we have some kind of category of classes then the answer is "clear".  

Comment: I meant answer to original question.

Comment: This is going nowhere because you're contradicting yourself: you can't possibly understand what a large category is without understanding what a map between classes is. It's the exact same definition as for sets: an operation that assigns an element of a class to each element in another class. This can be formalized in any set theory that can talk about classes (for example as a class of ordered pairs).


Comment: What you're struggling with are the set-theoretical foundations of any kind of category theory, which is quite different from your original question. There's plenty of references to be found online, starting for example from Jeremy's link above or this excellent survey by Mike Shulman: http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279. I suggest you research those a bit, and if you're not satisfied post a new question including the words "set theory" and "category theory" that's more likely to catch the eye of the experts.

Comment: By large category I meant a category with a proper class of objects and morphism sets, actual sets. As far as I know this is indeed called large. 
If you read my comments you would see that I said quiet clearly I did have a problem with the case where "hom sets" formed a class. The reference you gave, does not seem to actually talk about this case. (I think Mike addresses "All morphisms form a class but "hom sets" are sets situation, I'd have to look more carefully to be sure.) But I would like to pause this conversation with you as it is not helpful to anyone.  

Comment: I know what you meant. The collection of all morphisms forms a proper class anyway, and even if you only want to talk about the individual hom-sets, they are indexed by a proper class, so you need maps of proper classes to define a large category no matter how you look at it.